# Way to auto update a column in database depending on time

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there any way or script that allows to auto update the column in my database everyday at midnight 12.For eg I have a column 'x' ,currently value in certain row under column 'x' is say 10, What I want is to reinitialize that value to 0 as the clock strikes 00:00:00.Is there any way to do this ?
My database details : mysql in phpmyadmin.
Scripts I am aware of : javascripts or php.

Comment: google `cron job`. Sets a script to run at prescribed intervals. Then research how host lets you set them up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MySQL's event scheduler

```
CREATE EVENT update_status ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-11-02 00:00:00' DO
  UPDATE your_table
  SET    x = 0
```

In order to make the event scheduler run you can add this in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
...
event_scheduler=ON
```

Read this for more info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to look on **`CRON`** jobs. This CRON Job runs every midnight.

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/yourscript.php
```

**yourscript.php**

```
<?php
//... make conn to db

//make use of query something like this

mysqli_query("UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = 0");
```

Comment: What if the server is windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EVENT event_scheduler_x
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2013-11-04 00:00:00'
DO UPDATE tbl
SET x = 0;
```