# Implementing an age attribute in a CRUD grid via MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I am familiar with MySQL, but not PHP and CRUD grids.

Let's say I have a CRUD grid up and running. I have an id, name, email, and date of birth. I want to create an age attribute that is based on the date attribute (so it updates based on the current date).

As a MySQL statement this is not too hard. I have the statement for doing so:

```
SELECT `name`, `dateOfBirth`, CURRENT_DATE,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, `dateOfBirth`, CURRENT_DATE) AS age
FROM customers;
```

My question is how you'd implement this into a CRUD grid. Do I need to make a bespoke column or is that not necessary? Any advice or help much appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain what a CRUD grid is.  Also, what is a bespoke column?

Comment: A CRUD grid is essentially a table displaying the contents of a MySQL database in a more attractive interface. It does so by using PHP to pull the information from the database.

A bespoke column is not proper jargon - what I meant was whether I need to write PHP for another column like I would for the other columns or if I could simply request the age column from the MySQL database.

Comment: Okay. You're simply looking to have a database column updated automatically. Perhaps you should look into cron jobs or event scheduling. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19749890/1911755

Comment: So there isn't a way to request the age by simply appending another MySQL statement?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. Request from where? Do you want to update the database or calculate the age given a request? If you're just looking to get the age on a request, why not let php do the timestamp diff?

Comment: I don't necessarily need a new attribute in the database. Your comment on PHP doing the timestamp diff is interesting though - how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [datetime diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

```
$birthday = new DateTime('1985-09-15');
$now = new DateTime();
$age = $birthday->diff($now);
echo $age->format('%Y years old');
```

Comment: I literally just typed that! Feeling ecstatic - thanks though!